# Is there a more efficient way to query ActiveRecord db for an object that exists, but then also have an object, if existing, defined?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, performance, activerecord

My current code looks like this

```
o = Order.where(email:"email")
if o.present?
  do_something_with(o.last)
else
  return "Message"
end
```

I'm wondering if there are more efficiency gains to be had here. Particularly, it strikes me that there are different ways to optimize code for either of the if conditions.

In other words, if `o` does NOT exist, it would be better to have written:

```
if Order.where(email:"email").exists?
  # do_something_with(o.last) wouldn't work, you'd need to write
  # o = Order.where(email:"email").last
  # which requires another db call and is thus not efficient IF O WERE existing
else
  return "Message"
end
```

However if `o` does exist, it seems more optimal as is, since `o.last` can be called without another db hit. See code comments above.

Totally acceptable answer that there is not a more efficient way of doing this; what I have is generally acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `.where().last` fetches only the last record from the database in one query, which is pretty equivalent to your `.exists?` check (unless the overhead of sorting in the db is worse than in Ruby) so you can save some Ruby memory by doing something like this:

```rb
o = Order.where(email: "email").last
if o
  do_something_with(o)
else
  return "Message"
end
```

Although sometimes things that *seem* more efficient could turn out to be worse in practice.

If you only have a few emails that match that call, and your database is faster at returning a short list with no sorting than it is for a single item sorted, you might benefit from the "worse" call. At least until you call for an email that has millions of hits in your database, at which point Ruby will grind to a halt trying to fit all that in memory.

If it's worth improving, you should get in the habit of benchmarking.

Comment: yes you're right, but my question wasn't good. sorry i got mixed up. my code situation is actually like this: `all_os = Order.where(email:"email"); if all_os.present?; do_something_with(all_os)` that's why i was wondering if there are efficiency gains to be had by using `Order.where(email:"email").exists?` but then recognizing that if `all_os` does exist, it would be inefficient to query again like this: `do_something_with(Order.where(email:"email"))`. I understand your point around benchmarking and that it depends on size of query, was more thinking if there are rules of thumb